# initWithSize compared to didMoveToView

Tags: sprite-kit

I can't seem to understand why initWithSize and didMoveToView display different results.

```
-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:94.0/255.0 green:63.0/255.0 blue:107.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGSize _winSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height);

    SKSpriteNode *_playerSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Player"];
    _playerSprite.position = CGPointMake(_winSize.width - 50.0f, 60.0f);

    [self addChild:_playerSprite];


}
return self;   
}
```

This shows my sprite in the bottom lefthand corner when the orientation is landscape

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:94.0/255.0 green:63.0/255.0 blue:107.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGSize _winSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);

    SKSpriteNode *_playerSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Player"];
    _playerSprite.position = CGPointMake(_winSize.width - 50.0f, 60.0f);

    [self addChild:_playerSprite];
```

This shows my sprite in the bottom middle of the scene with the orientation on landscape.
I don't understand why I'm getting two different positions.

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit does not check the orientation in the init method. This only happens in subsequent methods.

This [article](http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions) from the YMC blog deals with "Setting Up Correct Scene Dimensions" and might add some additional clarity on the issue.

Comment: The article didn't fix the problem, i think the problem have to do with the unarchiveFromFile method